What is the optimal number of function evaluations?
You are given a function f that is defined only on the integers 1 to 200. The function is strictly unimodal and convex.  Strictly unimodal means it has exactly one local minimum and no two consecutive values are equal.
What is the minimum number of function evaluations you have to do in the worst case to find the minimum?

The outputs are real numbers without constraint?

@xnor yes. Does that make a difference?

Under required constrains binary search is better then ternary.

can we use a quantum computer :) ?

@FirstName LastName Any computer, as the number of function evaluations is criteria. :-)

@z100 I don’t think binary search works. How would you decide whether to go left or right ?

Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4967562/optimal-number-of-function-evaluations-when-only-defined-at-the-integers

I will ignore the fact that the function is convex. I suspect that this fact doesn't help the worst-case performance.
Definition
Let $x_{answer}$ be the value of $x$ which for $f(x)$ is minimal.
Game State
During the guessing process, only this information is relevant, which I'll call game state:

The value of $x$ which evaluates to the minimal value of $f(x)$ so far. Let's call this value $x_{best}$.
The range $[x_{lo}, x_{hi}]$ which must contain $x_{answer}$.

Example
Let's say we've made 5 guesses:

The game state is

$x_{best} = 8$
$x_{answer} \in [5, 9]$

Making a guess
When you make a guess (i.e. evaluate $f(x_{guess})$), your game state is updated. $f(x_{guess})$ will either be a new minimal value or it won't be. No other information is relevant.
Continuing the above example, if we evaluate $f(6)$ and it is a new minimum, then the new game state becomes:

$x_{best} = 6$
$x_{answer} \in [5, 7]$

Optimal strategy
The optimal strategy can be found by at any game state.
Let's define $G(\textbf{game state})$ as the worst-case number of remaining guesses to find $x_{answer}$ for a given game state.
$G$ can be defined recursively, and evaluated in code. (The details aren't very interesting. The N=20 example below should make the optimal strategy clear.)
Note that in the initial game state, $x_{best}$ is undefined. So, we consider the game states resulting from all possible initial guesses.
Results



N
worst-case number of guesses




1
1


2
2


3
3


4
3


5
4


6
4


7
4


8
5


9
5


10
5


11
5


12
5


$[13,20]$
6


$[21,33]$
7


$[34,54]$
8


$[55,88]$
9


$[89,143]$
10


$[144,232]$
11



So for $N=200$, $11$ guesses are needed in the worst case.
Illustrative example game for N=20
$x_{best}$ is marked in green.
Cells that can't contain the minimal value are blacked out.
Initial guess, $x_{guess} = 8$:

$x_{guess} = 13$, it is a new minimum:

$x_{guess} = 16$, it isn't a new minimum:

$x_{guess} = 11$, it isn't a new minimum:

$x_{guess} = 14$, it is a new minimum:

$x_{guess} = 15$, it isn't a new minimum:

($6$ total guesses, as expected.)
Note that when there are $20$ possible answers, the next guess is picked such that $12$ possible answers will remain (regardless of the answer).
In general, when there are $F_n - 1$ possible answers, the next guess is picked such that $F_{n-1} - 1$ possible answers will remain. ($F_n$ is the Fibonacci function, with $F_8 = 21$ and $F_7 = 13$.)

Best so far. Match Retudin's.

This is really creative, I had a hunch before that my binary search wasn't optimal with too many adjacent checks. Actually, here we are ensuring the number of checks will not increase, because if $F_k$
is the largest fibonacci less or equal to N, then $N−F_{k−1} \leq F_{k+1}−1−F_{k−1}=F_k - 1$. After 2 checks at the start you reduce to $F_k - 1$ and then you only require 1 check to reduce further to $F_{k-1} - 1$, so 2 + 1 * (k-3) evaluations (from $F_{k-2}$ to $F_2 = 1$). So $answer(N) = k-1$.

Do you need the same number of guesses no matter where the minimum is or is there a best and worst case for the algorithm?

For N=20 the algorithm always uses 6 guesses. In general, when $N=F_n-1$, you'll use exactly $n-2$ guesses. For other values of N, I didn't specify exactly what to do, but the best and worst case will be different.

What are the first two guess when you have the integers 1 to 200?  Would they be at 89 and 144? In general, are they always two consecutuve Fibonacci numbers?

You have some wiggle room. But, yeah, I think the simplest thing to do would be to make guesses as though the range were 1 to 232. (And guessing 200 instead of anything higher.) With this basic strategy, yes, your first two guesses will always be two consecutive Fibonacci numbers. However, you could start with 80 and 130 instead. The only important thing is that the ranges [1,80] and [130,200] have no more than $F_{11} = 89$ elements and [80,130) have no more than $F_{10} = 55$ elements.

I think the answer is:

 14 function evaluations

Order of queries:

 100, 101, 50, 51, 25, 26, 12, 13, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2

Let's analyze this below. Let $1\le x_m\le 200$ be such that $f(x_m)$ is minimum.
The only way to tell if $f(x_m)$ is minimum is that:

 $f(x_m-1) > f(x_m) < f(x_m+1)$, if they exist. Note that if instead we only know that $f(x_m-1) > f(x_m) < f(x_m+2)$, then $f(x_m+1)$ would also be a candidate for minima. So adjacent values play a vital role in this question.

Also, if we currently know $f(x)$, then how to tell which direction does the $x_m$ lie?

 just check $f(x+1)$. If $f(x+1) > f(x)$ then $x_m \le x$, otherwise $x_m \ge x$. Note that here adjacent differences are somewhat like gradients in deep learning, directing us towards the minima.

Explanation of the query sequence above:

 First we check $f(100)$ and $f(101)$. In the worst case: $f(100) < f(101)$, so we know $1 \le x_m \le 100$. Now we check $f(50)$ and $f(51)$. In the worst case: $f(50) < f(51)$. Then we check $f(25)$ and $f(26)$ and so on... with same logic.

How does the solution guarantee equal partition, so as to reduce the length of worst case segments?

 Note that once we evaluate a value, it stays with us forever. Now, if we have already evaluated $f(x)$ and $f(x+1)$ and concluded to move to the left, then the next points of evaluation are $f(\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\rfloor)$ and $f(\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\rfloor + 1)$. This is because there are exactly $\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\rfloor - 1$ un-evaluated integers on the left, and $\lceil{\frac{x}{2}}\rceil- 2$ un-evaluated integers on the right. Now, clearly $\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\rfloor - 1 \geq \lceil{\frac{x}{2}}\rceil- 2$ because $\lceil{\frac{x}{2}}\rceil - \lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\rfloor \leq 1$. Hence we successfully partition our range into equal sub-ranges considering the larger sub-range among them every time. This ensures that we cover the worst case scenarios in our strategy.


I will provide an easy approach (but I don’t think this is the optimized one).

 Firstly, let’s assume that f(1)<f(200) (if not, we can always flip the value order of function f to make it true.
 Now, we need to evaluate four values of function f, which are f(1),f(66),f(132),f(200).


 Next, compare the values. Since we have f(1)<f(200), there are only three situations which may occur:

 Wherein, the second and third situations both have two substitutions.
 (i). If the value comparison result belongs to the first situation (i.e. f(1)<f(2)<f(3)<f(4) ), then we can throw away the f(3) and f(4) and choose another two numbers to evaluate. 
 (ii). If the value comparison result belongs to the second situation (i.e. f(1)>f(2)<f(3)<f(4) ), then we can throw away the f(4) and choose another number to evaluate.
 (iii). If the value comparison result belongs to the second situation (i.e. f(1)>f(2)>f(3)<f(4) ), then we can throw away the f(1) and choose another number to evaluate.


 About how to choose the so-called ‘another numbers’, I think binary does work (as the picture shows below).



 In this way, we can continue to narrow the range of numbers we need to evaluate, and eventually find the minimum value. And, if I calculated correctly, in the worst case I need to estimate 11 values ​​to find the minimum

After discussion with @thisIs4d I realized that my approach is wrong, but I don't have a better way to improve it for now. So... I expect to learn from other better answers :D

I think you are close. If you start with f(66) and f(132), you will not need to check both f(1) and f(200).

@DanielMathias Yes, that's true. Actually if we think about it in reverse order then for every smaller interval f(a), f(b), f(c), f(d) (a<b<c<d) we we could have skipped either f(a) or f(d) by computing f(b) and f(c) beforehand. So, is it not be possible to reduce this solution even further? I sense exploitation vs exploration

Okay, got it. First of all, yes ternary makes more sense because to ensure that [a, b] contains lesser f values than [b, c] we need a fourth point. Ternary can equally divide the space and reduce worst cases faster as compared to binary search (like checking neighbor of midpoint). So ternary is the optimal solution here. Now, once we have endpoints checked, everytime we would only check +2 more points, so the +1 factor at the start of either f(1) or f(200) appears only once.

Consider all the values already evaluated. Denote S(n) =  f(n+1)-f(n) with 0 if negative (decreasing) and with 1 if positive (increase). So need to find the first 1 in the sequence (000....111), of course numbers of 1s or 0s can be less then 3. Binary search gives 9 as the theoretical lower bound for the original problem.

I get 16 evaluations total = 8 steps * 2 evaluations with some binary search.  But I am reluctant to post the answer as I do not understand the counts here: how do you get that you just need 10 evaluations with this approach??

@z100 notice that only a single function evaluation shall not provide you the consecutive difference. So for consecutive differences, you would require two function evaluations every time, making it 9*2 evaluations

@thisIs4d it is about lower bound whichever method used, not necessary including two consecutive values for each step.

@z100 Oh yes, sorry I misread, 9 is indeed a lower bound. Can we extend your logic and say that since in the worst case the minimum lies on k, 1 < k < 200, and to check that it indeed is a minimum we would require it to compare with f(k-1)  and f(k+1), that is S(k) and S(k+1), which will always require additional 2 checks. So does that mean 11 will be the lower bound?

@thisIs4d It is enough to find the first increase (or conclude it does not exist if the 200th is minimum) two consecutives is enough.

@z100  yeah that's fine. I was actually trying to make your lower bound stricter with above logic ... since we need 2 more function evaluations for them

@JulioDiEgidio Actually, 11 functional evaluations suffice with this order (consider worst cases at all times):
66, 133, 200, 88, 111, 95, 103, 97, 100, 98, 99
I have considered f(66) > f(133) < f(200) ... 66 to 133 contains 68 integers

As long as we divide in such a manner that largest interval contains <= 81 integers, we get the same number in the answer

@thisIs4d Totally agree. 11 is right. I've missed the last number in my count.

@thisIs4d Actually, my inspiration came from the Newton's iteration method for searching the local minima. I haven't learned algorithm systematically, and I'm not sure this is the best approach. And I gained a lot of knowledge from your analysis....!! Thanks

@thisIs4d My is: 1, 66, 132, 200,  99, 83, 75, 71, 69, 68, 67.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I believe the minimum is

 11 evaluations

Strategy

 The minimum is either to the left or right of the so far found minimum.
 One can divide one of those 2 areas with the next evaluation (and thus one should be larger than the other)
 It means the Fibonacci sequence applies here

Explicit:

 After f(144),f(89)
 if f(89) is smaller:
 3/ we have a 55-region (89-144) and a 89-region, f(55) will split the regions 55-34-55 and either the low or high size55-region is now known not to contain the minimum.
 4/ 55-34 or 34-55 can now similarly be split 34-21-34
 5/ 34-21 or 21-34 can now similarly be split 21-13-21
 6/ 21-13 or 13-21  can now similarly be split 13-8-13
 7/ 13-8  or 8-13  can now similarly be split 8-5-8
 8/ 8-5 or 5-8 can now similarly be split 5-3-5
 9/ 5-3 or 3-5 can now similarly be split 3-2-3
 10/ 3-2 or 2-3 can now similarly be split 2-1-2
 11/ 2-1 or 1-2, one can now check the last possible value
 If f(89) is larger:
  55-region (89-144) and a 56-region (144-200), so a smaller region than the previous i.e. 11 evaluations is also enough.

Example

 As an example, if 25 is the minimum the sequence could be:
 1..6 f(144)>f(89)>f(55)>f(34)>f(21)<f(13)
 7..8 f(21)>f(26)<f(29)
 9..10 f(26)>f(24)<f(23)
 11 f(24)>f(25)
 (note) Other paths to the minimum at 25 may apply depending on found values!


Well, 25 is an example, there are only 200 examples, maybe the most interesting are 1,2,88,89,100,101,199,200. But anyway, Fibonacci split  to ternary is as golden ratio to binary.
